# how do I parse output from ntpq?

Tags: bash, cron

I am fairly new to bash scripting... I have an issue with a cronjob where I get too many emails when "ntpq: read: Connection refused" error comes up. I want to create a conditional when this error shows up, DO NOT send the email.

However, I can't seem to parse the output from "nptq -nc peers". I did try to redirect the output of the cronjob to a `test.txt` file and then create another cronjob that parses that file. However, I feel like there is a better solution.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code for the cronjob

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=10101010101010101010000   # Set your limit in milliseconds here
offsets=$(/usr/sbin/ntpq -nc peers | /usr/bin/tail -n +3 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $9 }' | /usr/bin/tr -d '-')
for offset in ${offsets}; do
    if echo $offset $limit | awk '{exit $1>$2?0:1}'
            then
            echo "NTPD offset $offset > $limit. Please investigate"
            exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: That's the existing cronjob that you want to modify to avoid sending email (presumably by not exiting with a failure) when you see `ntpq: read: Connection refused` in the `ntpq` output? Are you trying to use the output in `offsets` for this check? What have you tried exactly? Is that output sent to standard output or standard error?

Comment: So for some reason when `ntpq -nc peers` returns `Connection refused`, it is not being read when I create the if statement. I think I wrote it like: `if $offset == "ntpq: read: Connection refused"; do exit 0 fi`

as for the redirect I tried to redirect the output with `> test.txt 2>&1`. However I feel the redirect is unnecessary

Comment: That message is probably going to standard error so just make sure you are catching that as part of the output. You shouldn't need a file for this though. Also see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to safely and correctly read data line-by-line in the shell.

Comment: sweet thanks! I believe I was able to capture the error
`error="$(/usr/sbin/ntpq -nc peers 2>&1)"`
I'll keep trying with the if statement. Not sure how I stop it from emailing when error... perhaps `exit 0`?

Comment: When `ntpq -nc peers` errors out, crontab automatically sends an email, which I don't want. Instead, I ended up redirecting the error to a log and adding a timestamp to the error. This link helped with the timestamp: http://mpcabd.xyz/adding-a-timestamp-to-command-output-in-linux/

Comment: cron shouldn't send an email if that errors on its own. It *might* send an email if you don't catch the error output and it hits cron's standard error though. (I'd have to brush up on my cron details to be sure.)

Comment: That script is badly written (it will lose runs of spaces in the input data because it doesn't quote properly and will also mangle data with escaping `\\` in them) and will perform poorly but ok.